# Asynchronous DB acces then toplevelApplication.close() and nothing is in the DB

Tags: apache-flex

I have such code:

```
try {
    var a = arr[index];
}
catch (e:Error){
    putErrorIntoSQLite(); // asynchronous DB access
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.close(); // closing the application
}
```

I susspect that it is an asynchronous DB access and there is no time to insert error message into the DB before closing the application.

The question: is how to prevent this? How to postpone the close() action and wait for the DB event?

What if instead of this

```
putErrorIntoSQLite(); // asynchronous DB access
```

I would use [Bindable] variable

```
bindableVar = "This is an error message";
```

that also uses events?

Comment: Catch the [closing](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/WindowedApplication.html#event:closing) event and cancel the closing action from there.

Comment: Yes I did this exactly like you said and it worked for me. Please anser my question in a normal way. I will be able to mark it as correct solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is probably correct.

There are [two ways to make database queries](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d29.html) with the API, one is synchronous and the other asynchronous. You can either switch to synchronous mode **or** listen for the `SQLEvent.RESULT` when you execute the SQL statement (and only close the application after that event is dispatched).

If you need further help, consider showing the code in your `putErrorIntoSQLite()` method.